# How do I create an image button in SwiftUI

Tags: button, imagebutton, swiftui

I have the following code to show an image:

```
struct TransactionsButtonView : View {
    var body: some View {
        return VStack {
            Image("Transactions")
            Text("Transactions")
                .font(.footnote)
            }.padding(.horizontal)
    }
}
```

This creates an image properly:

[image: Transactions Image]

However when I try to convert it to an image button, it only shows blue:

```
struct TransactionsButtonView : View {
    var body: some View {
        return VStack {
            Button(action: { self.showTransactions() }) {
                Image("Transactions")
            }
            Text("Transactions")
                .font(.footnote)
            }.padding(.horizontal)
    }

    func showTransactions() {

    }
}
```

[image: Blue Button]

How do I get my button to show the image?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to modify your image with the `renderingMode` by adding the following property:

```swift
Image("Transactions").renderingMode(.original)
```